# Last element not being removed in loop

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

I want to remove the card from the `@hand` array if it has the same rank as the given input. I'm looping through the entire array, why doesn't it get rid of the last card? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Output:

```
2 of Clubs
2 of Spades
2 of Hearts
2 of Diamonds
3 of Clubs
3 of Spades
------------
2 of Clubs
2 of Spades
2 of Hearts
2 of Diamonds
3 of Spades
```

Code:

```
deck = Deck.new
hand = Hand.new(deck.deal, deck.deal, deck.deal, deck.deal, deck.deal, deck.deal)
puts hand.to_s
hand.remove_cards("3")
puts "------------"
puts hand.to_s
```

Hand class:

```
class Hand

    def initialize(*cards)
        @hand = cards
    end

    def remove_cards(value)

        @hand.each_with_index do |hand_card, i|

            if hand_card.rank == value
                @hand.delete_at(i)
            end

        end
    end

    def to_s
        output = ""

        @hand.each do |card|
            output += card.to_s + "\n"
        end

        return output
    end
end
```

Card class:

```
class Card

    attr_reader :rank, :suit

    def initialize(rank, suit)
        @rank = rank
        @suit = suit
    end

    def to_s
        "#{@rank} of #{@suit}"
    end
end
```

Comment: The class `Deck` is not shown and the class `Card` is not used by the code you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove_cards(value)` has an issue:  one should not `delete` during iteration. The correct way would be to [`Array#reject!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) cards from a hand:

```
def remove_cards(value)
  @hands.reject! { |hand_card| hand_card.rank == value }
end
```

Comment: Is it bad practice to use delete during iteration or straight up wrong? And why so? My code is running as expected now, so thanks!

Comment: It’s straight up wrong. The internal iterator pointer gets confused when the array is “squeezed” after element deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this line

```
    @hands.each_with_index do |hand_card, i|
```

You have an instance variable `@hand`, not `@hands`

Comment: I noticed my typos straight after I posted my question (my text editor doesn't have colouring and it makes it easier to look over miss-typed variables). I edited the question and still have an issue.

Comment: BTW, you should afford using normal editor, rather than waste our time starring on your typos.

Comment: @mudasobwa Unfortunately I'm currently at work with locked down computers and no permissions to install any IDE's.

Comment: Discover https://c9.io/ or http://ideone.com/ or just google for “online ide”—there are tons around.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm relatively new to the coding world so sorry for any ignorance on my behalf.